# How to get ignored rows when using insert ignore query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with unique index created on two columns. I am using bulk insert method to insert the data. 
My query is

> Insert ignore into ---

I want to get the rows which were ignored during the query, How can I do this.

If I use insert query like

> Insert ... On duplicate key update

How can I get the rows which were updated.

Example-

Table "child_parent" has three columns, Id, child_id, parent_id.

Id is primary key. unique index is created for child_id and parent_id, so that combination of child_id and parent_id can not be repeated. When I insert I use Insert ignore into child_parent (Id,child_id,parent_id) values ?.

I want to get the rows which were ignored during this query.

If I use Insert into child_parent (Id,child_id,parent_id) values ? on duplicate key update

How can I get those rows which were updated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and also provide the complete INSERT which you are running.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have created an example for you.